# C: Typecasting with bitfields reverses values?

Tags: c, struct, casting, bit-fields

I am trying to cast a byte stream (raw data from serial port) into a structure for ease of use. I have managed to replicate the problem in a minimal working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    unsigned int source: 4;
    unsigned int destination: 4;
    char payload[15];
} packet;

int main(void)
{
    // machine 9 sends a message to machine 10 (A)
    char raw[20] = {0x9A, 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '!', 0};
    packet *message = (packet *)raw;
    printf("machine %d ", message->source);
    printf("says '%s' to ", message->payload);
    printf("machine %d.\n", message->destination);
    return 0;
}
```

I would expect the field `source` to get `9` from `0x9A` and `destination` to get `A` from `0x9A` so that the output says:

```
machine 9 says 'Hello!' to machine 10.
```

But I get:

```
machine 10 says 'Hello!' to machine 9.
```

Any idea why this might be so?

Comment: `packet *message = (packet *)raw;` invokes undefined behavior in several ways. There's no guarantee about alignment and it's a strict aliasing violation (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule). Additionally, there are few guarantees how these bitfields are stored interally inside the struct.

Comment: Many details about bitfields are implementation defined. You cannot rely on any specific order in memory.

Comment: Additionally, `0x9A` may be too large to fit inside a `char`. Never use the `char` type for storing raw binary data, since it has implementation-defined signedness. Use `uint8_t`/`unsigned char` instead.

Comment: Just my opinion, but: If you're trying to read/write data to/from streams, and if you want "ease of use", do *not* try to define a C struct that exactly matches your byte stream format.  It's an attractive and very popular technique, and it seems easy enough at first, but it's not; it's actually a miserable slog, rife with implementation-defined behavior and unportabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to cast a byte stream (raw data from serial port) into a structure for ease of use.

Interpreting a raw byte sequence in some random protocol as the representation of a structure type requires taking the target ABI into account for full details of structure layout, including bitfields, and perhaps also understanding and applying the C extensions made available by your compiler.  Since it is ABI- and compiler-dependent, the result is usually non-portable.

> I have managed to replicate the problem in a minimal working example: [...]
> I would expect [...]

There is not much you can safely expect here without referring to the ABI.  It includes

- the `source` and `destination` bitfields are packed into adjacent ranges of bits in the same "addressible storage unit".
- the ASU containing those starts at the first byte of the overall structure.

But you **cannot** assume

- anything about the size of the ASU containing the bitfields (other than it is no smaller than the smallest addressable unit of storage), or
- the relative order of the bitfields within it, or
- if it is larger than 8 bits, *which* 8 bits of it are used to store the two bitfields' representations. Nor
- whether the storage for `payload` starts with the next byte following the ASU, or
- whether the last byte of the `payload` member is the last byte of the overall structure.

> I get:
>
> ```
> machine 10 says 'Hello!' to machine 9.
> ```
>
> Any idea why this might be so?

The machine seems to do what you appear to have expected with accessing the `char` array via a `packet *`, though that behavior is in fact undefined.  That reveals that the machine has chosen a 1-byte ASU for the two bitfields, without any padding between that and the `payload`, and that it lays out the bitfields starting at the least-significant end of the ASU.  That is well within the bounds of the C implementation's discretion.

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to cast a byte stream (raw data from serial port) into a structure for ease of use.

```
char raw[20] = {0x9A, 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '!', 0};
packet *message = (packet *)raw;
```

This is poor code for several reasons.

- Alignment: `(packet *)raw` risks *undefined behavior* when the alignment needs of the structure `packet` exceed the alignment needs of a `char`.
- Size: The size of the members `.source` and `.destination` might not be packed in 1 byte.  Many attributes of bit-fields are implementation dependent.  The overall size of `raw[]` (20) may differ from `packet`.
- Aliasing.  Compiler can assume changes to `raw[20]` does not affect `message`.

---

What should be done depends on the unposted larger code.

Answer (score 1):

`0x9A` - lowest 4 bits `A`, highest 4 bits `9`.

In your structure if you compile with GCC member `source` (occupying lower nibble)  is assigned `A` and `destination` (occupying higher nibble) is assigned `9`

So program output is correct.